# Parsing char* to NSString stops at first new line in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I'm trying to convert a string returned from a library to an NSString to use with a separate Objective-C API, however whenever I parse the `char*` to a `NSString` it seems to stop at the first new line.

**Example:**

```
char *tst = "POST /servers HTTP/1.0\r\nContent-Type: test/json\r\nContent-Length:10\r\n\r\n1234567890";
NSLog(@"(TEST) : TST = %@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:tst]);
```

---

**Output:**

```
<Notice>: (TEST) : TST = POST /servers HTTP/1.0
```

> I'm not sure if this is it ACTUALLY not parsing past the first new line, or if NSLog simply isn't displaying the rest of the string past the first newline character. And that's what I'm trying to figure out.

---

### Edit:

---

> I've also tried replacing the `\r\n` instances with only `\n` with no change.

**Example:**

```
char *tst = "POST /servers HTTP/1.0\r\nContent-Type: test/json\r\nContent-Length:10\r\n\r\n1234567890";
NSString *tstStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:tst];
NSLog(@"(TEST) : TST = %@", [tstStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r\n" withString:@"\n"]);
```

---

**Output:**

```
<Notice>: (TEST) : TST = POST /servers HTTP/1.0
```

Comment: Your code is working fine. It shows log in next three lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should work. I just tried it and it worked for me, when looking at the debug log in Xcode.

Note that you'll actually get two new lines in your `NSLog` output, one for `\r` and one for `\n`.

Comment: Turns out the issue was the way I was greping my logs was missing the remaining lines. I feel rather stupid now.